# Click button (same id) to change color

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if in Javascript, you click on button BUT they all have same ID. If I click on the first one, it alerts the ID. But if i click on 2nd and 3rd nothing happens. Do I have to keep putting javascript or is there an easier way?

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Also, post your code in your question.

Comment: If you have multiple buttons with the same ID, that's *incorrect*.

Comment: @FrostyGamer150: Use a class instead, then use `getElemetntsByClassName` (and loop over it to set the event handlers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change those ID's to a `class`, and then iterate over that set and assign click handlers:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button1');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function() {
        color=this.value;
        console.log(color);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor= "#" + color;
        if (color!=null && color!="") {
            setCookie1("color",color,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uqVv5/2/

Comment: @FrostyGamer150 -- No problem, be sure to mark it when ya can

Answer (score 2):

An id must be unique. Never use same ID on more than one element.
Use class if you need more than one.

Answer (score 0):

As one commenter posted you have to use a unique ID for your buttons.  What's happening is that only the first element in the DOM is getting the onclick function assignment.  Here's a fiddler that shows how to do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/VayxA/

Here's the change

```
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = handleColorClick;
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = handleColorClick;
document.getElementById('button3').onclick = handleColorClick;

function handleColorClick(e) {

    e = e || window.event;
    var targ = e.target || e.srcElement;
    color =targ.value;
    document.body.style.backgroundColor= "#" + color;
     if (color!=null && color!="") {
          setCookie1("color",color,1);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I just upvoted tymeJV's answer. A much more elegant way to handle it.